# PHP different path names spaces and autoloading not working

Tags: php, namespaces, php-5.3, autoload

I'm trying to implement autoloading in Php5.3 using namespaces but I'm having some issues and don't know why it's not working.

I have a basic directory structure of

```
/root
--bootstrap.php
--test.php
--/src
----/com
------/a
--------Foo.php
------/b
--------Bar.php
```

bootstrap.php

```
<?php
function __autoload($class) {  
    // convert namespace to full file path  
    echo $class.'<br>';
    $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';  
    require_once($class);  
}
```

Foo.php

```
<?php
namespace src\com\a {

    class Foo {

        public function write() {
            echo "write";
        }
    }
}
```

Bar.php

```
<?php

use \src\com\a\Foo;

namespace src\com\b {

    class Bar {

        public function write() {
            $foo = new Foo();
            $foo->write();
        }
    }
}
```

test.php

```
<?php
use \src\com\b\Bar;
require_once("bootstrap.php");

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->write();
```

So the basic premise is call Bar, which in turn includes Foo and calls the write method

output:

```
src\com\b\Bar
src\com\b\Foo
```

But when I try and autoload it thinks Foo is in the namespace of src/com/b because that is the namespace of Bar and therefore it doesn't load.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like **bar.php** should be:

```
<?php


namespace src\com\b;
use \src\com\a\Foo;

    class Bar {

        public function write() {
            $foo = new Foo();
            $foo->write();
        }
    }

?>
```